# Windows 8.1 Store App development

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

Can I develop Win 8.1 Store App by using VS 2013 Express and Windows software development kit (SDK) 8.1 on My Win 7 Laptop ? Should I install Win 8.1 on My Laptop or Can I Use Win 7 with Above Tools ?

[Windows software development kit 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/bg162891#Requirements)

Comment: Why don't you give a try....

Comment: Your link says you can use it on W7, doesn't it?

Comment: @InderKumarRathore At this moment I don't have any of the above tools installed on my machine.So If I can't do the Win Store App 8.1 dev with above, I don't need VS 2013 right now.So spending time for that will waste my time.

Comment: @LucasHarada Me too feels that It can.But most of the folks are telling cannot :(

Comment: @Sampath This is kinda ambiguous, because maybe you can use the SDK on Windows 7 to develop only Windows 7 "apps", which is one option given. But I would still give it a try, that's a bit weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your link is for Desktop development, not Windows Store development (scroll to the top to see Windows | Dev Center - Desktop). Please refer to [this link](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compatibility-2013). At the middle you will find the `Visual Studio 2013 support for Windows Store app and Windows Phone development` section. This section defines what OS is required for development. In the section you will that Express for Windows requires Windows 8.1 to build Windows Store apps.

Answer (score 2):

You need Windows 8.1. Modern App Store development cannot be done on Windows 7.

Comment: Can you look at the link which I shared above.It says it can (as per my understanding) ?

Comment: Seems like that download contains .NET Framework 4.5.1 SDK, which would work on windows 7, so that's why they listed windows 7 as a supported platform. As usual the naming seems to be off. But I am confident that you cannot develop windows store apps on windows 7.